# Strange entry in tcpdump info for Rsyslog Message

Tags: linux, tcpdump, rsyslog

I have a problem with rsyslog.It works as a log collector for some devices. When I check with TCP dump i see bellow line is coming.

```
Facility user (1), Severity info (6)
    Msg: 1 2014-01-26T15:21:25.345+03:00 XXX_XXX-Node1 [|syslog]
15:21:37.526894 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 245, id 36018, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 708) xxx.syslog > xxx.syslog: SYSLOG, length: 680
```

Length is 680. Before we upgrade the remote end it was same length and it was working fine. Nothing changed except version of remote end ( log sender ) But there is a strange [|syslog] entry there and i can not see the message.

Does anybody before hit kind of issue ? Do you have any ideas why it could happen ?

Thanks
Suner

Answer (score 0):

By default `tcpdump` does not capture the entire packet.  If you read the `tcpdump` man page, you'll find information about the `-s` option, which says:

```
   -s     Snarf snaplen bytes of data from each  packet  rather  than  the
          default  of 65535 bytes.  Packets truncated because of a limited
          snapshot are indicated in the output  with  ``[|proto]'',  where
          proto  is the name of the protocol level at which the truncation
          has occurred...
```

Your output contains `[|syslog]`, which indicates the packet was truncated.  Try specifying a larger value (e.g., `tcpdump -s 1500 ...`).